# Using ref in a repetitive environment

Tags: aurelia

I'm using a custom element to print the length of an input element. I got it working in a regular environment, but I have trouble creating unique refs in a `repeat.for` environment

I've tried using combinations of `ref=name$index` or `ref=name${$index}`, but none of them work so far.

In a non-repetitive environment, this works

```html
<div class="row">
    <label>
        Name
        <my-custom-element field.bind="name"></my-custom-element>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            ref="name"
            value.bind="name"
            maxlength="150" />
    </label>
</div>
```

However, once I use repeat for, it stops working, cause I am using `field.bind` and `ref` wrongly. E.g.

```html
<div repeat.for="item of items" class="row">
    <label>
        Name
        <my-custom-element field.bind="name${$index}"></my-custom-element>
        <input
            type="text"
            name="name${$index}"
            ref="name${$index}"
            value.bind="item.name"
            maxlength="150" />
    </label>
</div>
```

I'm just trying to make the ref look something like `name0`, `name1`, `name2` etc, so that it is unique.

The error looks like `Parser Error: Unconsumed token { at column 5 in expression [name${$index}]`

Comment: I'm not sure how it works outside of the repeater - you have multiple binding to the 
 same "name" property. one of element type  (using ref), and one is a string (value.bind). please share your view model or a working fiddle so we can help more.

Comment: Why would you use ref for this? If all you want to show is the length of the filled text, just bind on the same field you value.bind the input element to and use a value converter to count the number of characters. If your scenario is dumbed down and more complex IRL, please provide a runnable example, you can easily do this with https://codesandbox.io/s/zw9zjy0683

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through `items`, which presumably is an array of objects having a `name` property. I think you want something more like the following:

```
<div repeat.for="item of items" class="row">
<label>
    Name
    <my-custom-element field.bind="item.name"></my-custom-element>
    <input
        type="text"
        name="item.name"
        ref="item.name"
        value.bind="item.name"
        maxlength="150" />
</label>
```

Comment: You are correct about `items`, however, `ref="item.name"` + `<my-custom-element field.bind="item.name"></my-custom-element>` won't work. It will just set the name value to `[object HTMLInputElement]`